# Question closed as a duplicate of a question which is deleted

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions

I came across a question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4114745/resources-on-learning-to-develop-android-apps which is closed as a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1114287/good-book-for-beginning-android-development and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3350447/the-best-book-for-programming-in-android. Both of these questions are deleted. In this case, how the future visitors will be benefited by the "Possible Duplicates" links?

Comment: They won't. I guess the duplicate closure could simply be changed to a "not constructive" one.

Comment: I think we just need one canonical question across all StackExchange sites that reads "Are book requests on topic? Answer: NO" and we can all link to that everywhere.

Comment: @JonW: The books tag has been burned and will not come back again :)

Comment: @Won't That won't stop the questions coming in though. "I have a question about what is the best C++ book... hmm, no 'book' tag so I'll just tag it C++ instead"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In such case just flag that question, select *other* flagging reason and describe it there. Moderator will handle it properly. Moderator either un-delete the duplicate question (if it is suitable for the site) or re-open the question or delete the current question (if it is also not suitable for the site).